# How to convert csv file content from one format(usual csv format) to another format (supported by salesforce)?

Tags: java, csv

I am working with mule esb to store data to salesforce cloud. so in that in need to convert following format Latitude,Longitude,Proximity

> 23.2241356,72.629232,0,
>   23.2241357,72.629233,5,
>   23.2241358,72.629234,0,
>   23.2241359,72.629235,5,

into following format,

```
 {proximity__c=23.2241361, longitude__c=72.629237, latitude__c=5.0},
 {proximity__c=23.2241362, longitude__c=72.629238, latitude__c=0.0},           
 {proximity__c=23.2241363, longitude__c=72.629239, latitude__c=5.0},         
 {proximity__c=23.2241364, longitude__c=72.62924, latitude__c=0.0},
```

How to achieve this through java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the possible solution.

```
 FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outPutFile);
             br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileToRead));
             writer.append("[");
             while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
              {
                String[] products = line.split(splitBy);
                writer.append(" {proximity__c= " + products[0] + " , longitude__c="+products[1] +" , latitude__c=" + products[2]  + "},");
                writer.append("\n");     
              }
  writer.append("]");
  writer.flush();
  writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep latitude,longitude and proximity in a collection such as HashMap or ArrayList or in some other thing as Collection of Objects

Just iterate this using for loop while doing iteration just perform basic string concatenation that's enough.

-- Update

```
public class Geo {

    private String lat;
    private String long;
    private String proximity;



    void setLat(String Lat){
        lat = Lat;
    }

    void setLong(String Long){
        long = Long;
    }

    void setProximity(String Proximity){
        proximity = Proximity;
    }

    String getLat(){
        return lat;
    }

    String getLong(){
        return long;
    }

    String getProxmity(){
        return proximity;
    }
}


HashMap<String, Geo> map = new HashMap<String, Geo>();


Geo g1=new Geo();
//set lat,long,proximity
map.put(“Geo”,g1);

Geo g2=new Geo();
//set lat,long,proximity
map.put(“Geo”,g2);

Create as many objects as you want and add to the Hash



Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();

String CSV=“”;

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
       Geo g= pair.getValue();

       if(CSV.length!=0)
        CSV=CSV+”,”

       CSV=CSV+“{proximity__c=”+g.getProxmity()+”, longitude__c=”+g.getLong()+”, latitude__c=”+g.getLat());
    }

   // if(CSV.length!=0)
  //  CSV = CSV.substring(0, CSV.length()-1);
```

Comment: If you have any doubt ,ask me

Comment: Thank You. can you walk me through some basic codes ? It will be great helpful for me.

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan - I have added the code.The code itself is self-explanatory

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you ?

Comment: Yes Bro.Its fine for me. Thank You.

Comment: @SaurabhChauhan - I am really happy ..that I helped you :)